# Finding the mean/average for a data set

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics

I was trying to find mean of this data set, I tried using AVERAGE, IQR and also T statistic, but was not able to get what would be the right mean of the data set below, can anyone please help how can I best find the mean. Thank you.

```
-36.64%
-47.15%
112.43%
-5.25%
35.08%
30.17%
38.05%
5.70%
-21.85%
-18.04%
2.73%
0.24%
8.36%
117.35%
-40.26%
-15.71%
-4.01%
6.24%
-57.36%
-18.74%
182.71%
-83.38%
```

Comment: Howso does `AVERAGE()` not work for you since that would typically return the mean? What is your desired result here?

Comment: But the, AVERAGE() will consider the outliers also, if I try to remove the outlier using quartiles, the IQR is very small its just 0.24, so what would be the right way to remove the correct outliers to get a near good mean

Comment: You don't really explain what it is you are trying. Finding a mean/average usually considers outliers. Why don't you want outliers, what exactly is the expected result? Are you looking for the trimmed or rather [truncated mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_mean)?

Comment: Why not use averageif() or averageifs() and specify limits to control outliers? Have you tried GEOMEAN(), HARMEAN(), TRIMMEAN() or MEDIAN()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you write I believe you are looking for the trimmed or rather truncated mean, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_mean).

There is an Excel function called `TRIMMEAN()` where you can specify a range of numbers and where the 2nd parameter takes the fractional number of data points you want to trim from the data points.

For example:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=TRIMMEAN(A1:A22,0.2)
```

Here we excluded 20% of the outliers in our mean.

Comment: This seems very helpful, Thanks so much